# Lumen Container.php trying to build class it doesn't need to

Tags: php, elasticsearch, lumen

I am currently using Lumen to build an API and am also playing around with Elastic Search. I have set up a service called GeocodeService with a Service Provider which, at the moment, is building the Elastic Search client and injecting it into the GeocodeService. My code for those classes is as follows.

GeocodeService.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Services;

use App\Models\ElasticSearch\Geocode;
use Elasticsearch\Client;

class GeocodeService
{
    protected $client;

    public function __construct(
        Client $client
    )
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }
}
```

GeocodeServiceProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use App\Services\GeocodeService;
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

class GeocodeServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();

        return new GeocodeService($client);
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is this.

```
BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 824:
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $retries ]] in class Elasticsearch\Transport
```

Now it looks like Lumen is trying to build the transport class when I don't need it too. See the below lines at the top of the call stack.

```
in Container.php line 824
at Container->resolveNonClass(object(ReflectionParameter)) in Container.php line 799
at Container->getDependencies(array(object(ReflectionParameter), object(ReflectionParameter), object(ReflectionParameter), object(ReflectionParameter)), array()) in Container.php line 772
at Container->build('Elasticsearch\Transport', array()) in Container.php line 627
at Container->make('Elasticsearch\Transport', array()) in Application.php line 447
at Application->make('Elasticsearch\Transport') in Container.php line 838
```

If I call dd($client) in the first line of the constructor in the GeocodeService class then I get the output of the Client object with no errors.

So my question is does anyone know the source of this issue and if there is anything I can do to prevent it?

If you need any further information let me know.

Thanks in advance for any responses!

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the implementation of `Elasticsearch\Client` into Container. Something like (*in your service provider*):

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Elasticsearch\Client;
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(Client::class, function () {
            return ClientBuilder::create()->build();
        });
    }
}
```

When you want to instantiate `App\Services\GeocodeService` don't use `new` way, like:

```
$geocodeService = new App\Services\GeocodeService(
    Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build()
);
```

Use `Container::make` method:

```
$geocodeService = app(App\Services\GeocodeService::class);

// or
$geocodeService = app()->make(App\Services\Geocode::class);

// or via Facade
// make sure you have uncommented '$app->withFacades()' in
// bootstrap/app.php file
$geocodeService = App::make(App\Services\Geocode::class);
```

Comment: hey , i am also getting this issue : my code is like 

$this->app->bind('\ElasticSearch\Client', function ($app) {
            return new \Elasticsearch\Client();
        });

Iinjected Client in my controller .. its trying to get internal Transport class .. any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried using `Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build()` instead of `new \Elasticsearch\Client()`?

Comment: Hi Krisan, thanks for the quick response .. i figured out the issue .. 1st thing .. had to use the builder as you said .. 2nd issue i was writing ElasticSearch rather than Elasticsearch all the places .. bad type :( .. took me 3hrs to figure out ..